# How do I repeat the number in the command code?

Tags: for-loop

I'm a newbie of programming, and i have a basic question. 
The bottom is the code I made to extract Excel data.

```
import os
path = "./data" 
file_list = os.listdir(path)
from openpyxl import load_workbook
results = []
for file_name_raw in file_list:
    file_name = "./data/"+file_name_raw 
    wb = load_workbook(filename=file_name, data_only=True)
    Ad = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Advanced') 

    result = [] 
    **result.append(Ad['C1'].value)
    result.append(Ad['C2'].value)    
    result.append(Ad['C3'].value)
    result.append(Ad['C4'].value)    
    result.append(Ad['C5'].value)
    ...
    result.append(Ad['C100'].value)**
    results.append(result)
print(results)
```

If i want to repeat the number in the *result.append(Ad['C **number** ].value)* 
how can i make a code? Is there a way to use for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in a for loop.
Define a range for your repetitions, let's say you want to do `result.append(...)`  for 100 times, then:
*Assuming you are using python*

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    result.append(Ad['C' + str(i) ].value)
```

OR

By specifying a limit:

```
n = 100  
for i in range(1, n):
    result.append(Ad['C' + str(i) ].value)
```